# aws iot core Billing API- get bill for individual devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-billing

I am using  **get_cost_and_usage** from [cost explorer](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage) API. I want to get billing details for individual things. I followed their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html) and  created a new billing group named (**user:company**) Inside managed option of IOT Core. Added 4 new devices inside this newly created biling group with tagName **user:company**  and value **IPMS** . Then in **Cost Allocation Tags** console, I Activated this tag (**user:company**).

But I am unable to get billing related to these things. Here is my python code

```
response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
       'Start': '2019-07-01',
       'End': '2019-07-16'
    },
    Granularity='MONTHLY',
    Filter={
        'Tags':{
            'Key': 'user:company',
            'Values': [
               'IPMS'
            ]
        }
    },
    Metrics=[
        'UnblendedCost',
    ],
    GroupBy=[
         {
            'Type': 'TAG',
            'Key': 'user:company'
         },
    ]),
```

and here is response

```
{"ResponseMetadata": {"RetryAttempts": 0, "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"x-amzn-requestid": "034a2efb-1ba2-4272-b595-d07d0e5c9931", "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1", "content-length": "216", "date": "Thu, 18 Jul 2019 16:49:33 GMT"}, "RequestId": "034a2efb-1ba2-4272-b595-d07d0e5c9931"}, "GroupDefinitions": [{"Key": "user:company", "Type": "TAG"}], "ResultsByTime": [{"TimePeriod": {"End": "2019-07-16", "Start": "2019-07-01"}, "Total": {"UnblendedCost": {"Amount": "0", "Unit": "USD"}}, "Estimated": true, "Groups": []}]}
```

event I am not able to get my defined tag in **get_tags** API

here is sample code

```
response = client.get_tags(

TimePeriod={
    'Start': '2019-07-01',
    'End': '2019-07-16'
},
```

)

and here is response

```
{"TotalSize": 1, "ReturnSize": 1, "ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "bdbdfb9e-fd84-44c7-9ab2-2f9d4cf1ecdc", "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"date": "Thu, 18 Jul 2019 16:50:55 GMT", "x-amzn-requestid": "bdbdfb9e-fd84-44c7-9ab2-2f9d4cf1ecdc", "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1", "content-length": "55"}, "RetryAttempts": 0}, "Tags": ["aws:createdBy"]}
```

Comment: Before debugging your code - can you please share if you're going to Cost Explorer - do you see your tags? Are you sure you enabled them in the billing tags? If you're running without the filter, are you getting any results?

Comment: @Dvir669, I am using free tier account so not sure if they provide this functionality for free tier. and Yes I have enable  tags in cost Explorer from UI. If I am running without any filter, I am getting aggregated cost. I want cost for each thing seperately

Comment: Hey, just to make sure we're talking about the same thing: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/activate-built-in-tags.html  - Have you enabled the custom tags you added?

Comment: @Dvir669 yes, I have already Activated "Cost allocation Tags" and Activated user defined Tags

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what the problem is. I took your code as-is, ran it on my account (python 3.6) and it is working well - changed the tags to my own and it's working. So either the tags are misspelled, or there was still no data when you ran it on the timeframe specified. Try running it today with the current date as "End date"